# Bargraph shortcode in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

So I'm attempting to create a bargraph shortcode. I wanted to be able to get the width from the text inside the li, but I can't seem to get it, it comes undefined. I'm not an expert at jquery so forgive me.

For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
        var top = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
        if (top > 10) 
        {
            jQuery(".bar").animate({ width: '20%' }, 2000)
        }
    });
});
```

Okay, that animates  fine at a pre-set width. I then tried changing the '20%' to a variable, which calls a function that should theoretically get the text inside the li element.

For example:

```
function name() {
          jQuery('.bar').text()};
var barLength = name();
```

Hm, how would I get the value inside the li element? Maybe there is an easier way? Also, because each bar length should be different, I'd use an 'each' loop right? Like for each .bar, get the value and set the width as that, that would be okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
        function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
            var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();

            var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
            var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

            return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
        }


        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (isScrolledIntoView(jQuery('.bargraph'))) {
                jQuery(".bar10").css({ "width": "10%" })
                jQuery(".bar20").css({ "width": "20%" })
                jQuery(".bar30").css({ "width": "30%" })
                jQuery(".bar40").css({ "width": "40%" })
                jQuery(".bar50").css({ "width": "50%" })
                jQuery(".bar60").css({ "width": "60%" })
                jQuery(".bar70").css({ "width": "70%" })
                jQuery(".bar80").css({ "width": "80%" })
                jQuery(".bar90").css({ "width": "90%" })
                jQuery(".bar100").css({ "width": "100%" })
            }

        });
    });
});
```